# Capture all click events and discard unallowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, click

I develop a web GUI for a special tablet. This tablet is running with Linux and the used browser is Chromium. The application is a web application with PHP, HTML5, JQuery and JavaScript. Now I run into a problem. The screen is a touchscreen and the user is able to navigate through the application by touch the screen. However now we decided to add a feature for saving electricity. This feature will shutdown the background light after three minutes. To turn on the backlight again, the user should touch the screen again. This leads to this problem, because on any touch the buttons are also pressed even if the background light is shutdown. I want to prevent this by discarding all clicks on the touchscreen if a cookie is set. If this cookie is not set the touchscreen and the application should work as desired. How can I solve this problem?

I installed an event listener to register all clicks and to reset the time.

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
     $.get('php/timeupdate.php', function(){});
}, false);
```

Code used to stop the execution:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    $.get('php/getwakeup.php', function(e){
        if(e==='true'){
            //event.preventDefault(); // I tried all three possibilities
            //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    // get your cookie 
    if( cookie is set ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

event.stopPropagation(); stops every event handling from where you called it =)

EDIT:

You have to set your $.get call synchronous or do it completely diffrent. Take a look at the [jQuery.Ajax documenation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There is a parameter called "async".

But be careful unless the call is ready nothing else will be executed on you page! So if your script doesn't answer nothing else will work on your site.

The better solution would be setting ja recurring call that will get the information you need. Set it to every two seconds (setInterval is your friend here). If your response is true than set a global variable that you can check in your onDocumentClick event.

```
window.isBacklightOff = false;
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('php/timeupdate.php', function(e) { window.isBacklightOff = !!e; })
}, 2000);

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    // get your cookie 
    if( window.isBacklightOff === true ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. Neither event.PreventDefault() nor event.stopImmediatePropagation() are working.

Comment: pls post the snippet where you try execute the event.stopPropagation()

Comment: I added your code snippet to my page. The only thing I changed is that I use a php script to get the status. But the debug shows that javascript is executed before it executes the clicked action.

Comment: Your problem is that $.get is an async call. So everything else will be executed while $.get is calling your php script! So what you need is to call this synchronously.
Take y lock at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
There is an option called "async" which you need to set to false.

Comment: Unfortunatetly a synchronous request does not solve this issue. I receive this warning: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: look at my second solution that I added to my answer :) this should work, if you use it the right way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80371/discussion-between-sebastian-hens-and-irgendw-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

When the back light goes off you can set some flag *handleEvents=false;*
So when the flag is on don't handle any events.
Now when the back light is on you can set *handleEvents = true.*

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    // get your flag say handleEvents
    if( !handleEvents ) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    } else {
        //do your biz logic send ajax..etc
    }

});
```

Reason why your code above is not working:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    $.get('php/getwakeup.php', function(e){
        if(e==='true'){
            //event.preventDefault(); // I tried all three possibilities
            //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
  });
```

The function inside *$.get* is async and called on success in that you are setting the event to stop propagating...well by that time when the success function is called the event is already complete and has called all the listeners.
So in short you must not do the event *stop propagation inside the success function*.

Comment: A PHP script is managing the background light. So I can only use PHP to set a variable. Unfortunatetly PHP is not able to set JS variables.